# Can I profit on Brexit having a modest amount of Pound Sterling?

Tags: united-kingdom, stock-markets, market-indexes, brexit

Knowing the Brexit is coming, is there any way I can profit on that?

I'm willing to speculate a small amount of money just for fun, but if there was a less risky way of profiting on Brexit, I'm willing to invest a modest amount.

Do you have any pointers I could use, to profit on Brexit?

Could you give an example scenario what can happen with international and domestic (to the UK) markets after Brexit?

I know it's a broad question, but hopefully, this will trigger a discussion that could be split into smaller, more specific questions.

Many thanks!

Comment: I'd say you can profit by not having any sterling when it happens, but that's highly subjective :)

Comment: Unfortunately not.  It's as impossible to predict as any other currency pair.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose there was a general consensus that GBP would depreciate against (say) EUR following Brexit.

Then suppose everyone sold GBP. At some point, GBP would fall below fair value as judged by actual commerce - e.g. you can buy British goods or services more cheaply than those sourced from the eurozone. People would likely start buying GBP to pay for them, pushing up the GBP.

Anticipating this, people might instead buy GBP to profit from the 'sheep', leading to an appreciation of the currency, against the initial consensus.

Market movements don't predictably follow the dictates of logic (even that sketched above) and any profitable niche tends to get filled. If you model the market as a dynamic system, it might be reasonable to say that markets tend to revert to some kind of reality-based steady state. But even if that happens, recall the Shilling/Keynes aphorism:

> The market can remain irrational longer than you can remain solvent.
>   [- Quote Investigator](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/08/09/remain-solvent/)

**Bottom line**: currency speculation is called *speculation* for good reason.